# Selenium Maven Setup - One Empty Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I'm trying to set up a Java Selenium test using the recommended Maven instructions found here:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

and here:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp

I have maven installed and working.

I've copied the example pom.xml, changing only the project name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>SeleniumTest</groupId>
        <artifactId>SeleniumTest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>2.44.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                    <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Using

```
mvn clean install
```

runs without any errors. The target directory is created, containing SeleniumTest-1.0.jar and the maven-archiver directory. The problem is that my Eclipse project can't resolve the Selenium classes. I've copied the example Java driver class, modifying the imports based on my project layout:

```
import Selenium.*;
import Selenium.target.*;

public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        // Alternatively the same thing can be done like this
        // driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The classes "WebDriver", "WebElement", "WebDriverWait", and "ExpectedCondition" can't be resolved. Trying to use the imports in the example

```
import Selenium.By;
import Selenium.WebDriver;
import Selenium.WebElement;
import Selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import Selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import Selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

all fail.

I looked into the jar downloaded by Maven, SeleniumTest-1.0.jar, and it is effectively empty. It only contains the META-INF directory.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I just can't figure it out. I feel like I'm missing something in my pom.xml, but I can't find anything on Selenium's site that helps. Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Running `mvn clean install` using this POM file will install YOUR artifact in your local Maven repository, not your dependencies. Is the issue here that you can't develop the project represented by this POM because Eclipse cannot find the Selenium dependencies you have listed? Or are you developing _another_ project that uses this jar as a dependency? Go to `$HOME/.m2/repository/org/seleniumhq/selenium` and see if Maven downloaded the Selenium library for the version you specified. There should be a jar file in there with all the classes you need.

Comment: Which Eclipse-Maven plugin do you have installed? Do you have the Maven nature added to your project?

Comment: @SiKing I'm not using a Eclipse plugin. I'm just using the Maven through command line.

Comment: So that explains: "The problem is that my Eclipse project can't resolve the Selenium classes."

Comment: @RyanJ I guess I don't understand the instructions on the Selenium page. It states, "Your pom.xml file will look something like this. Create this file in the folder you created for your project. [...] Now, from a command-line, CD into the project directory and run maven as follows. [mvn clean install] This will download Selenium and all its dependencies and will add them to the project."

Comment: @CoryOwens no, you followed them properly, but that command produces results that are misleading you. `mvn install` installs the artifact described by the POM into the local repository, and as part of that lifecycle step, will download all required dependencies to the local Maven repository. Hence my question, did Maven in fact download those dependencies to the local repository? My original comment "... not your dependencies" was meant to illustrate that you're not _directly_ installing your dependencies to the repo with that command.

Comment: @SiKing - Yeah, I guess that was it. I installed m2e, and it was able to download and integrate all the Selenium dependencies easily.

Comment: @RyanJ - I think I'm just now starting to understand Maven; I was under the impression it actually downloaded the dependencies. If you look above at my import statements, I modified them thinking that the dependencies were supposed to be downloaded, rather than leaving in the correct "org.openqa.selenium[...]" location. Thanks for clearing that up.